# Put drop-down menu in alphabetical order in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, alphabetical

I'm using ruby on rails to create a database.  I added a drop-down menu for the form of one of my tables.  The drop-down menu is a foreign key from another table.  I'm trying to figure out how to put that drop-down menu in alphabetical order.

Here is my code for form.html.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :founder_id %><br />
  <%= f.select(:founder_id, @founders.map{|founder| [founder.founder_name, founder.id]}) %>
</div>
```

Is there anything I can change to get this to show up in my form in alphabetical order?  Any tips would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@founders.map{|founder| [founder.founder_name, founder.id]}.sort{|a,b| a.founder_name.downcase <=> b.founder_name.downcase}
```

This will solveyour problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add some sorting:

```
@founders.sort_by(&:founder_name).map{|founder| [founder.founder_name, founder.id]}
```

or

```
@founders.map{|founder| [founder.founder_name, founder.id]}.sort_by(&:first)
```

`f.select` will display the options in the same order that it gets them. Case insensitive sorting is left as an exercise.